# Workaround for `instanceof` using Locker Service?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

We have a lot of `instanceof` in our Javascript framework. In locker service, `instanceof` doesn't work for most HTML objects because it uses a `SecureElement` instead of the actual object (E.G. `HTMLElement`).

In [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm), they talk about using `typeof`, but for complex objects it's just useless.

I've tried to [use other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript) but `instanceof` is really the way to go and nothing seems to be compatible with Locker Service.

I've checked everywhere and found out that [Doug talked about JavaScript `Proxy` in Summer '17](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147759/lockerservice-with-jquery-bootstrap-giving-error/147762#147762) and it would solve my issue.

In the meantime, are there any workarounds or a way to have a "pre-pre-release" of Summer '17?

Comment: Very well asked question. +1 from me! Maybe Doug will weigh in here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way to get a "pre-pre-release" of Summer '17 that uses `Proxy`.

As a temporary solution until the release, have you tried verifying a subset of properties/methods on an object to try to determine what it is? [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object) has some interesting ideas. You can try something similar to Eugene's answer (maybe without the cloneNode check):

```
if(typeof node == "object" && "nodeType" in node &&
   node.nodeType === 1 && node.cloneNode) {
  // most probably this is a DOM node
}
```

And you can add `nodeName` checks to try to tell what element type it is. Of course, this isn't a perfect solution since it would pass for an object that contains all the checked for properties. You could add additional checks until you feel confident nothing would 'accidentally' pass.

Comment: I like the effort, but how could I implement that for every type of objects?, `HTMLElement` is only an example.

Where could I get the confirmation that `instanceof` will work in Summer '17?

On github, `SecureElement` seems to already have the proxy code.

Comment: @Marc-AntoineVeilleux Yes you can download the latest Aura open source project and play with it yourself. You won't be able to use it on the actual Lightning platform though. I did a simple test of `var div = document.createElement("div");` and `div instanceof HTMLElement` passes. Keep in mind that instanceof doesn't work across frame/window boundaries and LockerService does leverage an iframe to evaluate some code so it's hard to guarantee all use cases will work. Do you have something specific in mind you want to try?

Comment: Hi @TrevorBliss! I've just saw on the release notes (https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring17_release_notes.pdf) that "The restriction on using the instanceof operator in JavaScript code has been removed due to some framework refactoring.", but I am unable to use `div instanceof HTMLElement`, how can I make sure I have the lastest Locker Service / Lightning framework?

Comment: At this point all instances are running the framework version relevant to the release notes. There's a small caveat that's unclear, however. `instanceof` still doesn't work for DOM elements. We're still looking at backporting the fix for `instanceof` on DOM elements.

Comment: Should I open a ticket with you guys? How can I be notified when it will be done?

Comment: Yes feel free to open a case and share the case number here for us to track. Thanks.

Comment: Done, Case # 15789383