# DateTimePicker no longer working with LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I am using the module provided [here](https://github.com/nehakadam/DateTimePicker), which works without LockerService, but fails to create the modal or the backdrop in LockerService. I suspect it has something to do with the html generated by the module, but I am not sure.. I believe the library is ES5 compliant and has no unsafe-inline/eval..

Here is an example that works without LS but doesn't work with LS.

App.app

```
<aura:application implements="force:appHostable">
    <ltng:require styles="{!join(',',
    '/resource/datetime/DateTimePicker.min.css'}"/>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', '/resource/jquery',
    '/resource/moment',
    '/resource/momenttz',
    '/resource/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js',
    '/resource/datetime/DateTimePicker.js')}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initJS}"/>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

            <div aura:id="datetimepicker" id="datetimewrapper" class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-fixed-addon slds-hide">
              <span class="slds-form-element__addon" style="white-space: nowrap ;">This message is scheduled to send at : </span>
              <input aura:id="datetimetext" id="datetimetext" class="slds-input noborder" type="text" data-field="datetime" />

            </div>
            <div aura:id="dtBox" id="dtBox"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

AppController.js

```
({
    initJS : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        $(cmp.find('dtBox').getElement()).DateTimePicker({
      dateTimeFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm AA",
      minDateTime: moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A"),
      titleContentDateTime: "Schedule this message to be sent at ",
      setButtonContent: "Schedule"

    });
    }
})
```

I am using the unminified JS to see if there are any exceptions, but no exceptions are output to the console either.. Does anyone else have experience with similar libaries breaking once LS is enabled?

I am currently not using the native  component because of its limited capabilities (not able to restrict dates, not able to get minute or second precision, not able to have a unified date and time picker on desktop).

JQuery 3.1.1
jQuery DateTimePicker 0.1.37
Bootstrap 3.3.7
moment.tz 0.5.10
moment 2.17.1

Comment: That is a longish list of unversioned 3rd party javascript - its a bit hard to tell from that. Can you provide the version numbers for jquery etc? Also, in the browser's js debugger try configuring it to break on all exceptions (there will be a few in the Lightning framework (e.g. aura_prod.js) that are always there you will need to step past - very annoying I know) and I suspect you will see what the root cause is.

Comment: Also, there is a known issue with LS and momentjs (moment uses instanceof in a few spots) - there is a fix to Locker due out shortly in Spring'17 that addresses this (yes instanceof will finally be supported!).

Comment: In addition to what Doug said, we released a fix for Bootstrap tooltips and jQueryUI Datepicker in the 206.9 release. It started going to the app servers on 2/7/2017. Can you retry your scenario and let us know if the issue still persists?

Comment: @DougChasman : I edited the code so that the datetimepicker is initialized when i click a button, so that it's easier to read through the exceptions if there are any, but I don't see any exceptions being thrown from the point of creation of the picker to when the input box gets clicked ( to trigger the popup)

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa : I still experience the issue.

Comment: @JasonLee I have opened an investigation for this issue. W-3692245 is the investigation id, when you open a salesforce case through support, please reference this investigation number.

Comment: @JasonLee I retried with the markup that you provided above. In my repro. I used the non-minified versions of the js libraries. The date time picker seems to work fine. Here's a screen recording: https://youtu.be/JbSyVBuFZKM

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa : I just tried it again and it seems like it's working, possibly Spring 2017 kicking in?

Comment: Great @JasonLee. Thanks for confirming. Yeah, depending on which server your org is in, the Spring 17 update might have happened over the weekend. All the test instances got Spring 17 during January. The particular fix for date picker went in a patch release for Spring 17, 206.8 to be exact(I noticed that I mentioned 206.9 in an earlier comment. That was a mistake. It was fixed in 206.8).

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa thank you, also do you know when the instanceof patch for LockerService is being released? I think Doug mentioned that it's soon but I can't find a date :)

Comment: 206.9, which is being released this week. Its scheduled to be deployed to all instances by Thursday afternoon(PST). If you are on sandbox, you might get it by tomorrow morning :)

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa : Is the instanceof issue completely resolved? I am seeing issues in another module (clipboard.js), and that module also uses instanceof to see if the object passed to its constructor is an HTMLElement.

Comment: @JasonLee instanceof check for HTMLElement doesn't seem to be working. We have a bug filed for that: W-3564510

Comment: @JasonLee http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153846/workaround-for-instanceof-using-locker-service/153861 And with that I will stop hijacking this thread